# I have an issue iterating a map and changing a value in it

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, stl

I have a hard time iterating through a map and changing a value in it.

```
cout << "HELLO! Please enter your name to sign up" << endl;
            cin >> name;
            for (it1 = abcCustomers.begin(); it1 != abcCustomers.end(); it1++)
            {
                if (it1->first == name)
                {
                    invalid = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    it1->second.setName(name);
                    it1->first = name;
                }
            }
```

First of all, it doesn't even get into the for loop. Secondly, it gives me an error in the
"it1->first=name;"

```
error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`std::map` is a container key/value pairs where the key is immutable.

The error message is exactly because you are trying to assign to `it1->first` that is declared constant and cannot be changed. If you want to change the key of an element you need to remove the pair and insert a new one.

Also you are looping and trying to change the first element that doesn't match and to me it doesn't really make much sense. Looks like instead you were trying to add a new element only if not already present and this can be done with:

```
if (abcCustomers.find(name) != abcCustomers.end()) {
    invalid = true;
} else {
    abcCustomers[name] = name;
}
```

using `std::map::find` is going also to be much faster than iterating over all the elements of the map because it's a O(log N) operation instead of O(N). This is actually the main reason for which `std::map` was created.

Comment: `if (!abcCustomers.emplace(name, name).second) { invalid = true; }` would be even better.

Comment: @Jarod42: depending on the definition of "better" :-)

Comment: One lookup vs 2 in your case. It seems to me that readability is equivalent.

Comment: @Jarod42: IMO not for someone that is currently thinking to scan an `std::map` to look for an element.